# woocommerce plus minus icon not showing

Tags: woocommerce

I'm using enfold theme on 2 different websites but plus minus icon does not appear on single product page on one of these website .I have searched and checked and compared quantity-input.php and woocommerce-mod.js on both website and they are the same but it's showing on one and does not show on other one .here is urls to compare both :
http://doodkaam.com/product/1/

http://wikidood.com/product/1/

Answer (score 1):

WooCommerce 2.3+ has removed the quantity increment buttons. Here quoting from their announcement :

> We’ve also removed a couple of features:
>
> The +/- quantity increment buttons – `input type=”number”` is well
>   supported making this feature redundant.
>
> These features can be replaced using their plugin counterparts:
>   https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-quantity-increment/

Comment: thanks.. spent at least 3 hours looking for this solution. almost every theme from them hides the browser buttons :(